# jQuery: Run when scroll over a div of a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

so I have multiple divs of the same class below each other. I now want to trigger a "loading comments"-function every time a visitor scrolls to a new div. However, I have no idea how to track jQuery scroll over a div. The comments for each div should only be loaded once, my idea would be to save the current position in a variable and only load comments when the new scroll position is greater than the old one.

Can you please help me out?

EDIT: I created a image that shows what I need to do.
Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5YyZ.jpg

EDIT 2: SOLVED!
Solved with Viewport (thanks to Royi Namir)
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

My code:

```
load = $(".my-div:in-viewport").attr('id');
load_comments(load);
```

This is executed every second.

Comment: you should read about viewport

Comment: That sounds great, I am reading into this right now. Thanks!

Comment: Solved, thanks! jQuery is really the greatest thing ever.

Comment: Please post your solution as the/an answer to your question, that way you can help people suffering the same problem in future.

Comment: @RoyiNamir post it as answer then

Comment: Was doing that right now, however, can't post as an answer so I'll edit my post.

Comment: Why can't you post as an answer?

Comment: I didn't have the permission to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should read about viewport

Viewport ads couple of extra selectors to jQuery. With these selectors you can check whether element is inside or outside of viewport. To see how it works check the demo.

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport/3x2.html