# need to show alert when i scroll down a certain div in html

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a div in the middle of body tag

```
<div id="place">

</div>
```

what i want to do is, when i scroll down and come across the div with id "place", i want to show an alert.the logic i set is when the window scroll postion is greater than the div from the window top , i execute alert . i know that my logic is stupid ! but i want to learn how to do this .

what i have tried so far

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

                var toElement = $("#place").position(); 
                if(scroll.positon() > toElement){
                        alert("hello");
                    }
            });
```

i am new to jquery, so could you help me

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554580/jquery-run-when-scroll-over-a-div-of-a-certain-class?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var offset = $("#place").offset().top;

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= offset) {
        alert("hello");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. is it possible when the div is in the middle of the window?

Comment: the alert popped out when it touched the window top postion.

Comment: True, I didn't understand well when you wanted it to pop.
I'm no jQuery master and don't know if there's a way to detect the middle of the window, but you could add a value to the offset variable. ($(window).scrollTop() >= (offset - margin))

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger an event from your script after you have made the div visible using the .[trigger](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger) function

e.g

```
//declare event to run when div is visible
function isVisible(){
   alert("hi");
}

//hookup event
$('#place').bind('isVisible', isVisible);

//show div and trigger custom event in callback when div is visible
$('#place').show('slow', function(){
    $(this).trigger('isVisible');
});
```